# Spotfire-IronPython: Set FilePath property

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

In Spotfire, using ironpython... 
I am trying to set the 'FilePath' property. Here is my try:

Document.Properties["FilePath"] = "E:\Spotfire_Export"

Here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport", line unknown, in ExecuteForDebugging
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application", line unknown, in SetPropertyValue
  File "Spotfire.Dxp.Data", line unknown, in GetProperty
KeyError: The property named 'FilePath' could not be found.
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

you need to first create a Document Property called `FilePath`.

1. from the **Edit** menu select **Document Properties...**
2. click the **Properties** tab
3. click **Mew...**
4. enter `FilePath` for the Property Name
5. enter a **Description** (optional) and a temporary **Value** (required)
6. click **OK**, click **OK**
7. your code should work